# Best way to delete data from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, foreign-keys, primary-key

My situation is as follows:

I want to delete data from *multiple* tables (over 10) in the database.

One table `(PRICE)` will be used as the deletion trigger. E.g. if `STATUS = "VOID"` then delete data from this table, and subsequently all the others.

`PRICES` *primary key* is a *foreign key* for most of these other tables.

Note also that these other tables all link to one another.

Should I just create a *Join* between the 10 tables and use this join for the deletions?

Or else could I just link from PRICING to one other table and then link through to the rest of them using joins?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would use a join to delete? And are your foreign key constraints built with `on delete cascade`? If not why not just delete from each table in order, based on their relationships, with `PRICES` last?

Comment: If not why not just delete from each table in order, based on their relationships, with PRICES last? This sounds useful, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Could I use Hibernates cascading delete for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't complicate things. Just place all your DELETE statements in a Stored Procedure and pass it a key value. This is what I use to delete records related to a Student ID (#SQLServer)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeleteStudent]
    @StudentID varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @OldID varchar(10)
    DECLARE @Error int

    BEGIN TRY
        --grab the student from the tblStudents to be sure the ID exists!
        DECLARE StudentdIDCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT StudentID
        FROM tblStudents
        WHERE StudentID = @StudentID

        BEGIN TRY
            --Using the studentID found, proceed to delete all tables associated with the student before actually
            --deleting the tblStudents table row
            OPEN StudentdIDCursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM StudentdIDCursor INTO @OldID
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @Error = 0

                BEGIN TRANSACTION DeleteStudent

                DELETE tblApprenticeships WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblApprovedAbsences WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblAssessmentMarkbook WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblAttendance WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblCaveMeeting WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblEnrolmentInterestRegister WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblExceptionalStudents WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblExtendedAbsence WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblMidSemesterReports WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblNOKRegister WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblPreStartStudents WHERE pssEnrolledStudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblQuestionnaireResponse WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblShortCourseStudent WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblSignatures WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentActivityRegister WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentAddresses WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentAllergyRegister WHERE StudentIDAllergy = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentAssessItemReg WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentContactLog WHERE StudentIDContacted = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentCourseAffectiveNotes WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentCourseAffectiveReg WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentCourses WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentElementMarkbook WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentFees WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentFiles WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentMedicalConditionsRegister WHERE StudentIDMedicalCondition = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentProfile WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentProgramReg WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentQualAffectiveNotes WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentQualAffectiveReg WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentQualificationReg WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentTimetable WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentTimeTableAndAttendance WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentUnitOutcomes WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudentUnitRegister WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudFormativeAssessments WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblStudSummativeAssessments WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblTimetableClassStudents WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END
                DELETE tblWorkPlacement WHERE WkPlacementStudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END

                --Finally delete the tblStudents record itself
                DELETE tblStudents WHERE StudentID = @OldID
                SELECT @Error = CASE WHEN @@ERROR <> 0 THEN @@ERROR ELSE @Error END

                IF @Error <> 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DeleteStudent
                ELSE
                COMMIT TRANSACTION DeleteStudent

                FETCH NEXT FROM StudentdIDCursor INTO @OldID
            END
            CLOSE StudentdIDCursor
            DEALLOCATE StudentdIDCursor
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT  'Could not delete student! Error Message: '  + ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorDescription
        END CATCH
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 'Could not find that student in the database!'
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: What would the equivalent to this be, to delete using Hibernate/JPA?

Comment: @java123999 That's a totally different question. Why don't you create a new question refering to my answer above?